# Programmatically setting a templated Button's VisualStates

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, expression-blend

In my WP7 application, I have a ListBox populated with buttons. I have a 'Pressed' visual state configured, and it works great. However, I would like to disable that 'Pressed' visual state (temporarily set it to do nothing) while the ListBox is scrolling.

I've created an event handler for detecting when the ListBox is scrolling (using Peter Torr's blog entry [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/07/23/how-to-detect-when-a-list-is-scrolling-or-not.aspx). Using that event handler, how can I alter/disable that 'Pressed' visual state, and also return it to its originally (through XAML) defined state? The ListBox 'Generated Items' template is the button control, which itself is templated to use my custom 'Pressed' state animation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not execly what are you looking for, but you can try setting

```
myButton.IsEnabled = false;
```

I assume your goal is to prevent user from clicking a button while scrolling.